# How to convert Datastore Key to URL-safe format using PHP client library?

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to obtain a Google Cloud Datastore [URL-safe key](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6365503?hl=en) using the [PHP Google Cloud Client Library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.70.0/datastore/key).

The java client library provides the functions [`toUrlSafe`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/Key.java#L148) and [`fromUrlSafe`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/Key.java#L161) to serialize a Key object from/to an URL-safe string. What are the php equivalents?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud the most developed Libraries are for Java and Python. Unfortunately, as of today, that functionality doesn’t seem to be for PHP as per the [official documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.70.0/datastore/key). As you pointed, this is on the [github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-datastore) so I suggest you open a request on that site. It may be available in the future.